# How would you divide the html5 canvas into multiple areas to hide/show only parts

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas where I manually create rectangles to build a full individual chart diagramm. Doing some coloring and text placing etc...

How can I easily tell a certain area to hide itself and show again?

Can there be a object orient approach to divide the canvas somehow in areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a solution that works the way you want. Canvas element don't keep track of areas are elements like you know it from the dom. There are some things you can do:

- Think about using svg. SVG works more like html and can be manipulated via javascript/dom and css.
- Redraw the whole canvas with the elements you want to display. You don't have to do this manually. Some framework like paper.js or kinetic.js will help. These framework also have feature like layers.
- The canvas element has the api functions getImageData and putImageData. With these functions you can save an area of the canvas into a javascript array and blank the area using the canvas drawing functions. When needed, you can redraw the area with the putImageData function.

Comment: I totally switched to svg.

Comment: Here is a great framework that i use when working with svg and graphs: http://d3js.org/

Comment: @Alex: +1 nice reference to d3.  It's one of the best libs for data visualization I've ever come across (and I'm kinda old so I've seen many!).